# unit testing webbrowser module

Tags: drivers, python3, testing, webbrowser-app

I want to unit test a bunch of code that looks like this:

```
# First command. This will open reddit in your browser.
# -------------------------------------------------------------
    if 'open reddit' in command:
        url = 'https://www.reddit.com/'
        if not runtest:
            webbrowser.open(url)
            print('Done!')
            talktome.talkToMe('reddit is opening.')
        if runtest:
            return url
# -------------------------------------------------------------
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've written this unit test:

```
import unittest
import subprocess
from GreyMatter import julibrain
from SpeakAndHear import talktome


class TestBrain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_open_reddit(self):
        test = True
        testurl = julibrain.assistant('open reddit', 1, 2, test)
        #subprocess.call(['pip', 'list', '|', 'grep', 'webbrowser'])
        self.assertEqual(testurl, 'https://www.reddit.com/')
```

I invoke it on the command line:

```
python -m unittest test_julibrain.py
```

It gives me this output:

```
❯ more runtests.sh
python -m unittest test_julibrain.py                                                                                                                                          /0.0s
❯ more runtests.sh
python -m unittest test_julibrain.py                                                                                                                                          /0.0s
❯ ./runtests.sh
Package           Version   
----------------- ----------
autopep8          1.5.2     
beautifulsoup4    4.9.0     
certifi           2020.4.5.1
chardet           3.0.4     
click             7.1.1     
future            0.18.2    
gTTS              2.1.1     
gTTS-token        1.1.3     
idna              2.9       
isort             4.3.21    
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3     
mccabe            0.6.1     
mock              4.0.1     
MouseInfo         0.1.3     
mypy              0.770     
mypy-extensions   0.4.3     
numpy             1.18.1    
Pillow            7.1.1     
pip               20.0.2    
psutil            5.7.0     
PyAudio           0.2.11    
PyAutoGUI         0.9.50    
pycodestyle       2.5.0     
PyGetWindow       0.0.8     
pylint            2.4.4     
PyMsgBox          1.0.7     
pyperclip         1.8.0     
PyQt5             5.14.2    
PyQt5-sip         12.7.2    
PyRect            0.1.4     
PyScreeze         0.1.26    
python3-xlib      0.15      
PyTweening        1.0.3     
requests          2.23.0    
setuptools        45.2.0    
six               1.14.0    
soupsieve         2.0       
subprocess.run    0.0.8     
typed-ast         1.4.1     
typing-extensions 3.7.4.1   
urllib3           1.25.9    
vosk              0.3.3     
wheel             0.34.2    
wikipedia         1.4.0     
wrapt             1.11.2    
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.285s

OK
```

So I can test that the url is being set, but I don't know how to see if the webbrowser module is working.  If I run the code, it the webbrowser opens.  I don't want to open it.  I'd like to get back some sort of status that says the module has been imported, a webbroser object can be instantiated, and there are no problems.  After looking at the webbrowser doc, I have no idea how to do this.  Any ideas?  Thank you.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, using conda and python 3.6.1.  Cheers!

Comment: This looks like a general programming question which is off topic here but could be asked on stackoverflow. Please correct me if there is something Ubuntu-specific in your question that I have missed.

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend reading some books or online resources about unit testing. For example: you shouldn't differentiate in your code if a test is running or not because that makes your test useless. Your code could still fail if no test is running. You test if the method returns a certain string, although that is not even its purpose and it only returns it because you are testing it. Additionally, you usually only test your own code. You want to test if the webbrowser package works, but then you'd also have to test the unittest and subprocess packages etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I was asking on Stackoverflow.  My mistake.  I had too many tabs in my browser, and I often miss the obvious when heads down I'm composing something.  Sorry.